Parallelism for Qiskit's TrainableFidelityQuantumKernel and QuantumKernelTrainer
I want to train a kernel over 800 samples, which requires the calculation of 800*799/2 = 319600 kernel matrix elements per call to FidelityQuantumKernel.evaluate(). The feature map itself is medium size but not trivial, encoding around 500 datapoints per sample with alternated layers of angle encoding and circular entangling. It also has 6 to 18 trainable parameters.
I thought about parallelising over matrix elements and running it on an HPC (28-core nodes). I started with python's multiprocessing module parallelising within one node (sharing the memory). However, 28 processes wasn't enough so I added mpi4py to also use different nodes.
The performance improvement is much worse than I expected, so I'd like to know whether there's some silly mistake in this strategy. Also, suggestions on alternative strategies or even using GPUs are welcome.
Please find my code below, which extends the TrainableFidelityQuantumKernel class. The number of processes for multiprocess is passed on input to the child class. The number of mpi processes is just specified with mpirun -np <n>.
""" Parallel Trainable Quantum Kernel """

from mpi4py import MPI
from multiprocessing import Pool
from typing import Sequence
import logging
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter, ParameterVector
from qiskit_algorithms.state_fidelities import BaseStateFidelity
from qiskit_machine_learning.kernels import TrainableFidelityQuantumKernel

class ParallelTrainableFidelityQuantumKernel(TrainableFidelityQuantumKernel):
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        n_mp_pools: int = 1,
        feature_map: QuantumCircuit | None = None,
        fidelity: BaseStateFidelity | None = None,
        training_parameters: ParameterVector | Sequence[Parameter] | None = None,
        enforce_psd: bool = True,
        evaluate_duplicates: str = "off_diagonal",
    ) -> None:

        self.comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
        self.mpi_rank = self.comm.Get_rank() # individual process
        self.mpi_size = self.comm.Get_size() # num of process
        self.n_mp_pools = n_mp_pools

        logging.info(f"""Instantiated ParallelTrainableFidelityQuantumKernel with
                No. mpi processes: {self.mpi_size}
                No. mp pools per process: {self.n_mp_pools}
                 """)

        super().__init__(
            feature_map=feature_map,
            fidelity=fidelity,
            training_parameters=training_parameters,
            enforce_psd=enforce_psd,
            evaluate_duplicates=evaluate_duplicates,
        )
    
    # override TrainableFidelityQuantumKernel's _get_kernel_entries method
    def _get_kernel_entries(self, left_parameters: np.ndarray, right_parameters: np.ndarray) -> Sequence[float]:
        """
        Gets kernel entries by executing the underlying fidelity instance and getting the results
        back from the async job, using multiprocessing for parallelization while preserving order.
        Also supports mpi/multi-node parallelisation.
        """
        num_circuits = left_parameters.shape[0]
        kernel_entries = []

        if num_circuits != 0:
            mpi_chunk_sizes,mpi_displacements,mpi_chunk_indeces = self._get_chunk_indeces(num_circuits,self.mpi_size)

            # flatten arrays
            flat_left_parameters = left_parameters.flatten(order='C')
            flat_right_parameters = right_parameters.flatten(order='C')
            flat_rank_specific_left_parameters  = np.zeros((mpi_chunk_sizes[self.mpi_rank]*left_parameters.shape[1]), dtype=left_parameters.dtype)
            flat_rank_specific_right_parameters = np.zeros((mpi_chunk_sizes[self.mpi_rank]*left_parameters.shape[1]), dtype=right_parameters.dtype)
            augmented_mpi_chunk_sizes = [i*left_parameters.shape[1] for i in mpi_chunk_sizes] 
            augmented_mpi_displacements = [i*left_parameters.shape[1] for i in mpi_displacements] 

            # scatter
            self.comm.Scatterv([flat_left_parameters, augmented_mpi_chunk_sizes, augmented_mpi_displacements, MPI.DOUBLE], flat_rank_specific_left_parameters, root=0)
            self.comm.Scatterv([flat_right_parameters, augmented_mpi_chunk_sizes, augmented_mpi_displacements, MPI.DOUBLE], flat_rank_specific_right_parameters, root=0)

            # reshape
            rank_specific_left_parameters = flat_rank_specific_left_parameters.reshape(mpi_chunk_sizes[self.mpi_rank],left_parameters.shape[1],order='C')
            rank_specific_right_parameters = flat_rank_specific_right_parameters.reshape(mpi_chunk_sizes[self.mpi_rank],left_parameters.shape[1],order='C')

            pool_chunk_sizes,pool_chunk_displacements,pool_chunk_indeces = self._get_chunk_indeces(rank_specific_left_parameters.shape[0],self.n_mp_pools)

            with Pool(processes=self.n_mp_pools) as pool:
                results = pool.starmap(
                    self._process_pool_chunk,
                    [(i, rank_specific_left_parameters[start:end], 
                         rank_specific_right_parameters[start:end])
                     for i,(start,end) in enumerate(pool_chunk_indeces)]
                        )

            # Sort results based on the pool_chunk index and flatten
            results.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
            rank_specific_kernel_entries = np.array([item for _, sublist in results for item in sublist])

            kernel_entries = np.zeros(num_circuits,dtype=rank_specific_kernel_entries.dtype)
            self.comm.Gatherv(rank_specific_kernel_entries, [kernel_entries, mpi_chunk_sizes, mpi_displacements, MPI.DOUBLE], root=0)

            self.comm.Bcast(kernel_entries,root=0)

        return kernel_entries

    def _process_pool_chunk(self, pool_chunk_index: int, left_pool_chunk: np.ndarray, right_pool_chunk: np.ndarray) -> tuple[int, Sequence[float]]:
        """
        Process a pool_chunk of the parameters and return the pool_chunk index with the results.
        """
        pool_chunk_size = left_pool_chunk.shape[0]
        if self.max_circuits_per_job is None:
            job = self._fidelity.run(
                [self._feature_map] * pool_chunk_size,
                [self._feature_map] * pool_chunk_size,
                left_pool_chunk,
                right_pool_chunk,
            )
            return pool_chunk_index, job.result().fidelities
        else:
            # Implementation for max_circuits_per_job case goes here
            # This would involve splitting the pool_chunk into smaller batches
            # based on max_circuits_per_job
            pass

    @staticmethod
    def _get_chunk_indeces(total_elements,n_procs):
        chunk_size = total_elements // n_procs
        remainder  = total_elements % n_procs

        if chunk_size < 1:
            return [total_elements,], [0,], [(0,total_elements)]

        l_chunk_sizes = [chunk_size + 1 if i < remainder else chunk_size for i in range(n_procs)]
        l_displacements = [sum(l_chunk_sizes[:i]) for i in range(n_procs)]
        l_indeces=[
            (start, start + size) for (start,size) in zip(l_displacements,l_chunk_sizes)
                    ]
        return l_chunk_sizes,l_displacements,l_indeces
        

